# Move Tabs Using Fragment- Nested Tabs

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am new in android, especially in Xamarin Android C#. I have bottom navigation tabs and fragments. They are fragment_picture (tab_picture), fragment home (tab_home), fragment notifications (tab_notifications), fragment_profile (tab_profile). Inside fragment_picture (tab_picture), I have 2 tabs. They are fragment_camera(tab_camera), and fragment_gallery(tab_gallery). I want to move the tabs of fragment_picture such as when I click the tab_camera, it shows the XML of the tab_camera and when I click the tab_gallery, It shows the XML of the tab_gallery.

I don't use viewpager. I am just using fragments. The tab won't change the position to its XML. I've searched a lot in Google But, I still confused. Please help me

```
 using System;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Support.V4.App;
    using Android.Widget;

namespace MyPhotographicMemory.Droid.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment_Picture : Fragment
    {
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        private TabLayout.Tab tabGallery, tabCamera;
        Fragment fragment = null;


        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        public static Fragment_Picture NewInstance()
        {
            var frag2 = new Fragment_Picture { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag2;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentPicture, null);

            tabLayout = v.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.pictureTabLayout);

            tabLayout.TabSelected += (object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                switch (e.Tab.Position)
                {
                    case Resource.Layout.FragmentCamera: //Resource.Id.tabItem1
                        fragment = new Fragment_Camera();
                        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(0);
                        tab.Select();
                        break;
                    case Resource.Layout.FragmentGallery: //Resource.Id.tabItem1
                        fragment = new Fragment_Gallery();
                        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.GetTabAt(1);
                        tab1.Select();
                        break;

                }

            };
            return v;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like this GIF?

[image]

If so, you should achieve the nested tabs with fragment.

Here is my code when in my first fragment.

```
   public class Fragment1 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment1 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new Fragment1 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, null);
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView= view.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.mynested_bottom_navi);
            bottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
            LoadFragment(Resource.Id.tab_camera);
            return view;
        }

        private void BottomNavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadFragment(e.Item.ItemId);

        }
        //switch fragment by tab id.
        void LoadFragment(int id)
        {
           Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.tab_gallery:
                    fragment = Fragment_Gallery.NewInstance();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.tab_camera:
                    fragment = Fragment_Camera.NewInstance();
                    break;

            }
            if (fragment == null)
                return;

            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
               .Replace(Resource.Id.mynest_content_frame, fragment)
               .Commit();
        }
    }
```

Here is my demo, you can refer to it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XZE6YopdsvDHY8-DwXBxRpHz3oFlJbOR/view

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer(click `✔` in the upper left corner of this answer.), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. My issue is about the tab (in the top position). So, I have two tabs. They are bottom navigation tab and the second is tabs in top position. Currently, I have an issue with the top tabs but, your answer gives me insight. Thanks a lot for giving me your google drive link :D